# How to check SafeHtml type for null in Angular ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to Hide an div element if the SafeHtml(query) type is null.
Now the problem is if I am using *ngIf="query!=null" it won't works.

import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

Comment: can you please share your currenet code?

Comment: <div id="test" *ngIf="query!=null"  [innerHTML]="query"></div>                                              query: SafeHtml;

Comment: Seems SafeHtml is complex type that's why not able to equate with null checks.

Answer (score 2):

To check **Null** or **Empty String** you no need to check it explicitly.
Just check the variable inside `*ngIf` condition.

Please check this short example: [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a7bzzt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**TS**

```
query: SafeHtml;
htmlString = 
`<div style='background:gold'> 
    I am coming from controler with dynamic text --  <b> ${this.checkText} </b>
 </div>`;

constructor(domSantizer: DomSanitizer) {
   this.query = this.htmlString 
   ? domSantizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.htmlString) 
   :  ''; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="query">
    <b> Check with SafeHtml </b>
    <span [innerHTML]="query"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  checkNull = null;
  checkEmpty = "";
  checkText = "test";
  query:SafeHtml;
}

Comment: Can you try it for 'query' type.

Comment: I have updated the example, you can go and check it by removing the text. Once the ```htmlstring``` is empty the complete block will removed from ```DOM```

Comment: This is correct. It rules out `null`, `undefined`, and empty.